# Will I be able to push a Summer 15 package to a Winter 16 ORG?

Tags: managed-package, isv, winter16

My company is a Salesforce ISV partner.  We have a dev org that we package up and then push upgrades out to our customers as needed.  I realized that this weekend some of our customers will be upgraded to Winter 16, but our dev org will not be upgrade until next week.  If I need to make a fix in our dev org next week and push out that change to those upgraded customers, will that be possible?  Basically, can I install a Summer '15 managed package to a Winter '16 ORG?

I know this information is out there, somewhere, but I'm just unable to find it today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, packages are always forwards compatible. The only situation you have to watch out for is when your development package uses features that are not available to orgs. This only happens when Developer Editions are updated *before* all production instances have been updated, *and* you use features that only exist in the latest version. Since your org appears to be on the late update (e.g. later than the other orgs), you shouldn't have a problem. For example, I have a managed package on na1 that I have to remember not to update with the latest versions until after all production orgs are upgraded. Developer orgs on much newer instances, like na15, are generally immune from this effect, since they tend to be the last ones to be upgraded.